# How to Display User's Place on Snippet Google Maps Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps

I have google map and want to display user's place (like city) in snippet.
How to do that?

here's my current code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

var latitude = -7.034323799999999
var longitude = 110.42400399999997

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    mapView.delegate = self
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: Double(latitude), longitude: Double(longitude), zoom: 17)
    mapView.animate(to: camera)

    let markerImage = UIImage(named: "ic_home_detail_marker_location")
    let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(latitude), Double(longitude))
    marker.isDraggable = true
    marker.snippet = "\(marker.position)"
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker
    marker.iconView = markerView
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

}

Comment: For get the city you need to call geocode block of apple . https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the user's city or state name you have to use CLGeocoder.

```
var currentLatitude:Double!

var currentLongitude:Double!

var cityName:String!

var stateName:String!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print("locationManager function called")

    // Fetch current location coordinates

    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!

    currentLatitude = locValue.latitude

    currentLongitude = locValue.longitude

    print("Current Location = \(currentLatitude!), \(currentLongitude!)")

    // Zoom to current location

    let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: currentLatitude!, longitude: currentLongitude!, zoom: 17.0)

    viewMap.camera = camera

    // check for current city

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(locationManager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)

            return
        }

        if (placemarks?.count)! > 0 {

            let pm = placemarks?[0]

            self.cityName = (pm?.locality)!

            self.stateName = (pm?.administrativeArea)

            print("Current City: \(self.cityName!)")

            print("Curret State: \(self.stateName!)")

        }
        else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Now you have the current city stored in a variable.

The next step is that when the user touches a marker, it should display the cityname. For this to achieve implement this:

This delegate must be added:

```
GMSMapViewDelegate
```

and this is the marker function, when user taps on it.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    mapView.delegate = self
    marker.snippet = ("Current city: \(cityName!)")

    // return false so as to show the marker details or
    //   return true to hide marker details.

    return false
}
```